# Getting apm to work on Windows, no Atom folder

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to get `apm` working on Windows. I have Atom (1.2.4) installed.

I have read that Atom comes with `apm`, but people seem to point to:

`C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Atom\app\resources\app\apm\bin`

I have no *Atom* folder in my *Local* folder.

Does that mean I don't have `apm` installed at all..?

I need to add the executable to my `PATH` variables so I can run it from a command line, but I don't know where `apm` is installed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's here: `C:\Program Files\Atom\resources\app\apm\bin`.

There is a file called `apm` with no file extension that seems to be the `apm` command line utility.

The apm docs aren't much help, the [Installing](https://github.com/atom/apm#installing) section just references a:

> Atom > Install Shell Commands menu option

Which is a Mac thing, it doesn't exist on Windows.

Comment: The Windows installer will install `apm`, that's why *“Install Shell Commands”* might be greyed out on Windows. I'm not sure whether you resolved the problem, if so, you should click on the arrow to accept your own answer.

Comment: Thanks... *Install Shell Commands* isn't there at all, looks like it's a Mac only option. I will indeed mark this as answered, as soon as stack lets me ("You can accept your own answer in 2 days")... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Win7, installed Atom v1.15.0, the apm moved to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\atom\bin`.

You need to do:

**1. Setting above path to** 

`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System\Advanced system setting\Environment Variables`

**2. Restart the Windows' `cmd.exe` window, and try installing a package**

`apm install atom-beautify`

Hope this helps

---

Btw, on Windows platform, you may encounter compilation error wile install a package required `node-gyp` if you haven't installed a C++ compiler.

Installing one can help you out by:

**A.** Execute this command (from [here](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools)):

`npm install --global windows-build-tools`

OR

**B.** Installing [Visual C++ Build Tools (standalone C++ compiler, libraries and tools)](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)